# Creating overlay on child div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a overlay which is `50%` width of the parent width and `100%` height. But it's not working, what's going wrong?

```css
.parent {
  padding: 100px 0px;
  background: black;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 50px;
}

.child h1{
  color: red;
}

.overlay {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

A white overlay effect should appear behind the text, half the width of `.parent`

Comment: you defined width twice, one of them should be height

Answer (score 1):

- The element that you want the content relative to should have the `position: relative;` style. (Add it to the parent and remove it from the child)
- You've used `width` twice in `.overlay` (The second one should be `height`)

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 100px 0px;
  background: black;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 50px;
}

.child h1{
  color: red;
}

.overlay {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you were adding `width` two times in `.overlay` class. I presume that the second one is `height`.

Is that you are looking for?

```css
.parent {
  padding: 100px 0px;
  background: black;
}

.child {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 50px;
}

.child h1{
  color: red;
}

.overlay {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with height `100vh` to parent.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 50px;
}

.child h1 {
  color: red;
}

.overlay {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  padding: 100px 0px;
  background: black;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;


}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  top:0;
}

.child h1{
  color: red;
}

.overlay {
  width: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```